# Can not access Anaconda/Miniconda environment as virtualenv with pyenv

Tags: virtualenv, anaconda, conda, pyenv, miniconda

I'm showing you [the steps I use to create a virtualenv based on miniconda based on pyenv-virtualenv docs](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv#anaconda-and-miniconda). Finally you will see that the virtualenv was created but I can't access to it.

1.0. Check my initial pyenv versions:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/oscar/.python-version)
2.7.9
3.5.1
```

1.1 Install miniconda:

```
$ pyenv install miniconda3-4.0.5

$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/oscar/.python-version)
  2.7.9
  3.5.1
  miniconda3-4.0.5
```

1.2. Create the venvtest virtualenv based on miniconda:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv miniconda3-4.0.5 venvtest

$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/oscar/.python-version)
  2.7.9
  3.5.1
  miniconda3-4.0.5
  miniconda3-4.0.5/envs/venvtest
  venvtest
```

When I want to check if the virtualenv was created, It doesn't show it. So I can't no access to it :(

```
$ pyenv virtualenvs
  miniconda3-4.0.5 (created from /home/oscar/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.0.5)

$ pyenv activate ... (autocompleting)
--help            miniconda3-4.0.5  --unset
```

Please, I hope you can help me.

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/178

Comment: I doubt that it makes sense to create a virtualenv of miniconda in the first place. anaconda/miniconda installations ship `conda` as a way to create conda environments.

Comment: @cel I'm trying to accomplish this behavior: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv#anaconda-and-miniconda

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer. But a similar thing happened to me.

So I used

`source /Users/<user_name>/Applications/anaconda3/bin/activate <env_name>`

instead of

`source activate <env_name>`

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to not install `Miniconda` or `Anaconda` (herein refereed to as *conda) via `pyenv`. Instead, download the installer from the applicable site and install it as follows.

Eg. I downloaded the installer from the website to `~/Downloads`

```
% cd ~/Downloads
% ls | grep conda
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Run the installer:

```
% bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Now most importantly, at the end of the installer when you are prompted `Q) Do you wish the installer to initialize Miniconda3 by running conda init? [yes|no]`, choose `no`.

Note: If you choose yes, Miniconda or Anaconda will deploy changes into your ~/.bashrc which will start up the *conda environment every time you open a bash session. This will corrupt pyenv.

After the installer is complete, add the following functions* to your ~/.bashrc:

```
function aconda {
  eval "$(${HOME/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
}
function dconda { 
  conda deactivate 
}
```

* change the path to `conda` executable as required.

To launch the *conda environment, open any terminal and type `aconda` and to deactivate type `dconda` and that's it.

These instructions are for Linux but should port to Mac easily, not sure about windows though as I don't use it for my development.

I'm new to using the *conda environments and was surprised with the lack of simple instructions so I had to do a bunch of trial and error to get it so PyEnv, which I adore, working correctly. Hopefully this helps some others.

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's 2022, it's time for a new answer...
It appears that the current method for installs of *conda via pyenv is to manage the conda virtual environment with conda's commands.

From the pyenv-virtualenv [`README`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv):
"You can manage `conda` environments by `conda create` as same manner as standard Anaconda/Miniconda installations. To use those environments, you can use `pyenv activate` and `pyenv deactivate`... If `conda` is available, `pyenv virtualenv` will use it to create environment by `conda create`." See the [Github repo `README.md`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) for a command walk-through.